# Calling ILAsm global function from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ilasm

Suppose I have an ILAsm library with the following code:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib{}
.assembly TestMe{}
.module TestMe.dll
.method public static void PrintMe() cil managed 
{
    ldstr "I'm alive!"
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    ret
}
```

How can I call a global PrintMe() function from a C# code?

Comment: Just add a reference to the assembly that was built from this code.  Now it all works like you are familiar with in C#.

Comment: If I just add reference to the .dll, my .cs code does not see PrintMe() function.

Comment: You haven't yet written valid IL, use ildasm.exe to see what good IL looks like.  Methods must be part of a class.

Comment: My dll is valid. Global fields and methods are allowed in .Net and used e.g. by managed C++.

Comment: It doesn't.  Use ildasm.exe on a C++/CLI assembly and you'll see it adds free functions as methods to the hidden `<Module>` class.

Comment: <Module> was also added to my PrintMe(). Can we say that it too became a part of a class?

Comment: Ilasm.exe might be doing this by default, never tried to get this wrong intentionally.  If you see it back then, yes, I'd assume it followed CLR rules automatically and ensured that the method became part of a class.  That `<Module>` class is private which is why you can't get to it in C#.  Just declare a public class instead.

Comment: Yes, indeed, ilasm has no other choice except using that special case class `<Module>` as described in ECMA-335 "II.10.8 Global fields and methods"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can via reflection.. but not in any really useful way:

```
var module = Assembly.LoadFile("path_to_dll.dll").GetModules()[0]; 
// the first and only module in your assembly
var method = module.GetMethod("PrintMe");

method.Invoke(null, 
              BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, 
              null, 
              null, 
              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // Prints "I'm alive!" to console.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as far as I'm aware. C# only "knows" about methods declared in types - not at the top level. Move your method into a type.